# ASTParser - Replace for(;;) with for(;true;)

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree

I have an AST like

```
for(;;){/*...*/}
```

It means when I call

```
forStatement.getExpression()
```

I get `null`. But how to replace `null` with `BooleanLiteral` (`true`)? Thanks

Comment: `x = forStatement.getExpression(); if (x==null) x = true;`?

Comment: No, I need to modify AST

Comment: Is this for a specific tool?  It isn't specified in your question.  (The usual way to modify the AST is walk over the AST as a data structure and destructively modify it.  There are tools called program transformation systems that can accept the surface syntax enabling you to write literally, *for(;;) => for(;true;)* usually with some extra constraints on where it applies. Which of these is what you are asking about?